# How to call data from Django database to template (html)?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

**how to retrieve data from the database django. I have models.py like this :**

```
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.db import models

class Category(CMSPlugin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**and file cmsplugins.py like this :**

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from models import Category

class CategoryPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = Category
    name = _("Category Plugin")
    render_template = "about.html"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context['instance'] = instance
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(CategoryPlugin)
```

**how to retrieve a list of name to be displayed in html**?
Thanks before ^^

Comment: Shouldn't you be inheriting from `models.Model`?

Comment: Please go through the Django tutorials [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/). Part 3 of the tutorials helps you understand how to create user-Interface, views

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you should divide work in 3 parts.

- Models: All your db models and logic resides under it.
- Templates: Where you place your markup by passing in the least possible only relevant data for rendering.
- Routes (views): Your URL's are mapped to these methods in urls.py They Make a call to models and further pass in the processed data to templates so as to get rendered.

Follow the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) @jdotjdot gave in comments. Thats the way its done in Django.